# How do I access a dynamic property of a JSON object? (Node.js)

Tags: json, node.js, api, parsing

I'm sure a similar question has been asked and answered many times, but I guess I'm not wording this question properly as I have yet to find any response that works for me.

I am using Node to send an API request and am returning the data to my angular app as such:

```
app.get('/personInfo/:personName', function(req,res){

    Module.Person.getByName(req.params.personName)
    .then(function (person) {
        res.json(person);
    });
});
```

The app embraces the response, by the virtue of the following script:

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    $http.get('/personInfo/' + $scope.person.name).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

($scope.person is linked to some fields my .html file, and it seems to works fine)

I'm getting this back (assuming I passed johnny in via $scope.person.name)

```
johnny:Object
__proto__:Object
```

The first object contains the data I want ... so I cannot access its properties directly.

I am not able to perform a simple `response.id, response.name, response.profileIconId` etc. on this... I'm having to access it like this:

`response.johnny.property` ... which, obviously...

What am I doing wrong? Is there some form of formatting or parsing that I can use, either on server-level or client-level that will allow me to access the properties of the object directly without specifying a dynamic parent?

Comment: `$http.get('/personInfo/' + $scope.person.name)` is dangerous because it risks garbling the request (at best) or an injection attack (at worst) when the person name contains URL-special characters. **Always** encode data properly. In this case, use `encodeURIComponentI()`.

Comment: encodeURIComponent()? I changed a lot of things in these scripts to keep it simple. But I did not know of this before, I appreciate it.

Comment: check the server side code and see if `person` object contains something like `johny:{...}`.  That may be the reason you are getting response which you desribed

Comment: @VikashKesarwani when I log person, I simply get [object Object] - am I supposed to access some property?

Comment: @BarryD. log `JSON.stringify(person)` , it will print the string representation of the person, then you can verify the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so this seems to work...

I figured out through testing that person.x (x = the personName param) returns the object exactly how I want - So I'd need to do person.personName every time, so since I don't know the name, just pass in an unknown property which matches the parameter, and it works!

res.json(person[req.params.personName]);

returns:
`Object {id: 19897772, name: "Johnny", profile: 937, rank: 12, revisionDate: 1463522178000}`

and I can now do `response.id,name,profile etc.` ...

Comment: great, but it will be cleaner for your code if you edit Module.Person.getByName() to return data[personName]

Comment: `Module` represents a module that is connecting to an API behind the scene, so I used that code straight from the documentation - but I will consider this, thanks.